# How do I uninstall iconv from a Mac?

Tags: macos, uninstall, homebrew

I'm trying to get Homebrew working, and `brew doctor` returns several warnings, one of which is this:

```
Warning: The following libiconv files were detected in /usr/local:
include/iconv.h
Homebrew doesn't provide a libiconv formula, and expects to link against
the system version in /usr/lib.

If you have an alternate libiconv, many formulae will fail to compile or
link, especially if it wasn't compiled with the proper architectures.
```

I take it I have to uninstall iconv. How do I do this?

---

**UPDATE:** I'm going to just move that file aside for now as a temporary solution.

Comment: How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: I don't remember how I installed it, or even /if/ I did in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If there is nothing in `/usr/local` you want except Homebrew you can do this:

```
cd /usr/local && xcrun git clean -xfde /var
brew link `brew ls`
brew doctor
```

All that is left will be Homebrew.

It is possible you will get permission errors during the clean step. If so you can run it again inserting `sudo` before the `xcrun`. However do so with caution.

You can run `xcrun git clean -dn` first to see what would be removed.